# Visio VBA: How to make all text in Org Chart Bold

Tags: vba, formatting, visio

I would like to simplify updating my orgcharts in Visio.  So far I have a macro borrowed from here https://bvisual.net/2010/01/28/applying-selected-datagraphic-to-the-whole-document/ and written out below.  I would like to adapt it to make some changes to the format of the text withing shapes e.g. to make the font bold and potentially to change it's colour.  I'm finding it really difficult to find examples of this online so any help/suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

```
 Public Sub ApplyDataGraphicToDocument()
    Dim mstDG As Visio.Master
    Dim shp As Visio.Shape
    Dim pag As Visio.Page
    Dim firstProp As String

       If Visio.ActiveWindow.Selection.Count = 0 Then
           MsgBox "Please select a shape which already has data graphics"
           Exit Sub
       Else
           Set shp = Visio.ActiveWindow.Selection.PrimaryItem
          If shp.DataGraphic Is Nothing Then
               MsgBox "Please select a shape which already has data graphics"
              Exit Sub
           Else
              'Get the shapes DataGraphic master
              Set mstDG = shp.DataGraphic
               'Get the name of the first Shape Data row
              firstProp = "Prop." & _
 shp.CellsSRC(Visio.visSectionProp, 0, 0).RowNameU
           End If
      End If

       For Each pag In Visio.ActiveDocument.Pages
           If pag.Type = visTypeForeground Then
               For Each shp In pag.Shapes
           'Check that the named Shape Data row exists
                  If shp.CellExistsU(firstProp, Visio.visExistsAnywhere) Then
                      'Set the DataGraphic
                      shp.DataGraphic = mstDG
                                       End If
              Next
          End If
      Next

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the default OrgChart shapes, although it is **not officially supported**. To change the default shapes (make their font bold), you'll need to edit the templates (masters) for those OrgChart shapes. In the same blog you can find more information on customizing the OrgChart diagrams, here: https://bvisual.net/2012/05/08/creating-a-custom-org-chart-template-with-extra-properties

The procedure is mostly the same, just instead of adding the properties, you make the text bold.